# Circular table problem with condition

Tags: combinatorics

I just started my combinatorics class and want to check if my reasoning is correct

> there are 8 boys and 4 girls. How many ways can they be seated at a round table if there must always be two boys between any two consecutive girls?

My reasoning is we treat the $8$ boys as pairs, so we have $4$ pairs of boys to place say $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, and $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ girls. Since it is a round table there are $\dfrac{8!}{8}$ ways to do this. Then from here, I am not sure. I want to say the pair of boys can rearrange themselves 4! ways and similar for the girls hence the final answer should be $\dfrac{8!}{8}*(4!)^2?$

Comment: We must seat the table gbbgbbgbbgbb.  The end wraps around to the beginning.  We can count the number of ways to make 3 person clusters of 2 boys and a girl, and seat the 4 clusters, and then account for rotation.  Or we can seat the girls, exploiting what we know about rotational symmetries, and then seat the boys in the remaining spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the boys $A,B,\ldots, H$ and seat them around the table in $\frac{8!}{8}$ ways. Then girls can be seated between $(B,C)$, $(D,E)$, $(F,G)$, $(H,A)$. This can be done in $4!$ ways. Another possibility is, girls are seated between $(A,B)$, $(C,D)$, $(E,F)$, $(G,H)$. This can be achieved in $4!$ ways. Hence total is
$$\frac{8!}{8} \times (4!+4!)$$

Alternatively we can seat the girls first. Recall the $12$ positions of numbers of a clock. We let the girls seat at positions $12,3,9,6$. There are $\frac{4!}{4}$ ways. The boys occupy the positions of remaining $8$ numbers in $8!$ ways. So answer is
$$\frac{4!}{4}\times 8! = 3!\times 8!$$
same as above.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you giving two approaches. I understand the logic of the first approach more than the second. This might be a silly question as clearly, they both give the same number. But for the alternative option why we do not consider the rotational symmetry for the boys?

Comment: The rotational symmetry is fixed by seating the very first person from the total. Of $12$ people, we already chose the very first girl as the leader. We don't have to do it again for boys.

Comment: I understand! Thank you for the help.